# Canvas: arc(75,75,50,0,3.1415,true) draws oval instead of circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Why this code draws oval instead of circle at the position (75, 75) with the radius 50?

```
<canvas id=c1 style="width:400;height:400">
<script>
    ctx = c1.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#7ef';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75,75,50,0,Math.PI*2,true)
    ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you change this line:

```
<canvas id=c1 style="width:400;height:400">
```

to:

```
<canvas id=c1 width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

it should work. Don't use CSS to set Canvas sizes as this only affects the *element* but not the *bitmap* itself. For canvas you need to use it's dedicated properties (width/height) to also set the bitmap size or the bitmap is just stretched/scaled to match the size of the element.

The default size of canvas if not specified is 300x150 pixels. In this case those pixels are stretched (as an image) to 400x400 which is why you get an oval instead.

Comment: @exebook CSS affects only the element but not the bitmap. It's like an image of 300x150 set to css size 400x400, it would be stretched. A canvas is the same as an image, just edit-able.

Comment: so when I omit the canvas width/height parameters, they are set to some weird defaults?

Answer (score 6):

In cases where the size of the canvas is dynamic and not known at development time, you can set the size using JavaScript when you know that the browser has already positioned and sized the element appropriately:

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
```

This is useful when developing for mobile either as a website or a PhoneGap/Cordova app.

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks!